# IIS and Glassfish in Windows 7

Tags: iis, windows-7, glassfish

I installed the newest version of Windows 7.

This is my development box, so I have glassfish installed, which I use for Java applications. Also, I use IIS to run PHP applications. I run both servers on port 80, but never at the same time.

However, since I set up IIS, I can't get glassfish to run. In eclipse, it always gives the following error:

```
Port conflict: Please stop the server process using the same port as the one used by the Application Server.
A server process is already running on this port but we cannot determine if it's a GlassFish process (lack of info or credentials).If you do not find something else running on this port, check for antivirus software blocking or monitoring this port.
```

Edit: I tried turning off IIS, and even turned off the IIS feature. Still no luck.

I also ran netstat, and the following are showing up on ports that glassfish uses:

```
 Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
 TCP    0.0.0.0:80             NBSDTVL01574:0         LISTENING
 TCP    [::]:80                NBSDTVL01574:0         LISTENING
```

Thanks

Comment: Run "netstat -a -b" to see which process is listening to 0.0.0.0:80 and [::]:80 and then report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with my virtual machine.  A fresh copy fixed the issue.

Answer (score -2):

this happen because you select the same port number use by the iis and glashfish, i suggest you configure either of the two to use different port number.

Comment: Please explain to the user the reasoning behind the down vote.